# How to decide the Jordan normal form of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

I have the following matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0\\-1&3&0\\-1&1&2\end{bmatrix}

My matrix has characteristic polynomial $(X-2)^3$ and minimal polynomial $(X-2)^2$. How do I decide between the two following Jordan normal forms of this matrix?

\begin{bmatrix}2&1&0\\0&2&0\\0&0&2\end{bmatrix}

or

\begin{bmatrix}2&0&0\\0&2&1\\0&0&2\end{bmatrix}

Comment: they are the same

Comment: Jordan normal forms are unique *up to permutation of the Jordan blocks*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of them will do. That is, both of them are a Jordan normal form of your matrix.

Comment: Oh book uses only one of them without saying anything. Thank you :)

Comment: This depends on the convention that the Jordan basis of each generalised eigenspace begins or ends with eigenvectors.

Comment: @Bernard no, that would yield the one in the other answer. The difference in the question is how one orders the cyclic subspaces. By increasing or decreasing dimension. [That is assuming matrcies operate on the left.]

Answer (score 2):

They are equivalent Jordan normal form as also the following

$$\begin{bmatrix}2&0&0\\1&2&0\\0&0&2\end{bmatrix} \quad \begin{bmatrix}2&0&0\\0&2&0\\0&1&2\end{bmatrix}$$

which are sometimes also used.

Indeed the Jordan normal form is unique up to a permutation of the blocks.